# Loop into a PDO request to check if variable exists?

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I want to loop into DB to check if a variable exists, then when it doesn't exist I make an INSERT into DB. For instance :

```
$i = 1;
$string = $_POST['name'];
$req = $pdo->prepare('SELECT name FROM users WHERE name = ?');
$req->execute(array($string));
while($req->rowCount() > 0) {
    $name = $string . '-' . $i;
    // HERE IN NEED TO TEST THE EXISTENCE OF THE VAR ($name) INTO DB, BUT HOW?
    $i++
}
if ($name) {
    $string = $name;
}
$req = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO users (name) VALUES (?)');
$req->execute(array($string));
$req->closeCursor();
```

Comment: `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

Comment: ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE only works with Integer, right ? My problem is based on a string.

Comment: @XavierC.: What is the signifigance of `link` and `name`. I dont see you setting a value for `link` in your insert so how does that even get in the data? This entire process smells incredibly bad and the proper course of action is to revise the table structure and the logic but I dont understand the data or its usage so i cant make a recommendation. Also, Tycho is awesome ;-)

Comment: @prodigitalson : Sorry for my mistake, I just updated the code : it was "name", not "link". And yeah, Tycho is awesome! ;-)

Comment: @XavierC.: Ok so why do you even need a sequence number added to the `name`... Why not just use an `AUTO_INCREMENT` primary key and just keep inserting names?

Comment: Because I want to generate a unique link to show the user profile, like mywebsite/user/john-doe. If there still is a John Doe user, the link would be mywebsite/user/john-doe-1 and so on... I don't want to use id's like mywebsite/user/1. Does it make sense?

Comment: Ok that makes a bit more sense...

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not letting users choose a unique user name instead?

Comment: The only reason is I don't want to let them choose. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I finally find a way :

```
function profileLink(PDO $pdo, $string, $i=0)
{
    if ($i!=0) {
        $link = $string . '-' . $i;
    } else {
        $link = $string;
    }
    $req = $pdo->prepare('SELECT link FROM users WHERE link = ?');
    $req->execute(array($link));
    $nb = $req->rowCount();
    $req->closeCursor();
    if ($nb > 0) {
        $i++;
        return profileLink($pdo, $string, $i);
    } else {
        return $link;
    }
}
$link = profileLink($pdo, $link);
```